# How to find out if key is bad or not the same when trying to do openssl decryption

Tags: openssl

I am trying to write a library method to decrypt the data, the **decryptData** method is supplied by the **key, IV, encryptedData and decryptedData**:

**decryptData(unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* encryptedData, unsigned char* decryptedData)**

In the above method, the openSSL call order is like that:

1. EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new
2. EVP_DecryptInit_ex
3. EVP_DecryptUpdate
4. EVP_DecryptFinal_ex

Everything works fine with above method, what I am looking for error cases for bad **key**, how do I know that user provided a bad **key** to decrypt the data if above openSSL calls failed. These calls return only SUCCESS(1) or Failed(0).

I need to notify the user that the 'key' is bad or not the same key during encryption.

Any help or pointer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If by "bad key" you mean a key different from the one used to encrypt the data, you can not know that it is different. Decryption is a mathematical operation, and it will work with any key you give it as long as it is in a valid format -- a key is just a set of numbers, after all. But if the decryption key is different from the key used to encrypt the data, the plaintext will be different, or garbage. If you want the user to validate that the plaintext is good, you will need something in addition to encryption, for example provide the plaintext checksum.